# How to make `append after command` draw something behind the text of a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

## The context

I know how to use `append after command` to draw a cross inside a rectangle (see code block and image below)

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, fit}

\tikzset{
  mystyle/.style = {
    rectangle,
    draw,
    append after command={
      node [
        fit = (\tikzlastnode),
        inner sep = -\pgflinewidth,
        cross out,
        draw = blue
      ] {}
    }
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node [mystyle] {a};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: a node with a rectangle border with "a" as the text inside the node and a cross inside the rectangle but above the text]

As can be seen in the image above, the blue cross is drawn on top of the text of the node. I want to change this behavior. I want the text to be on top of the blue cross so that text is not covered by anything.

## The question

How can I make the text of the node not be covered by the blue cross drawn by `append after command`?

One way to accomplish this is by making `append after command` draw the cross below the "a". Is there an option that I can pass to `append after command` to set that behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the node "background" with a `path picture`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    mybg/.style={
        path picture={
            \draw[blue] (path picture bounding box.north west) -- (path picture bounding box.south east)
            (path picture bounding box.north east) -- (path picture bounding box.south west);
        }
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw,mybg] {a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```